# find invalid characters in string

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a select statement that will show any invalid characters in Customer number field.

A vaild customer number starts with the captial letter N then 10 digits, can be zero to 9.

Something like,

```
SELECT (CustomerField, 'N[0-9](10)') <> '' 
FROM CustomerTable;
```

Comment: `regexp_like` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`regexp_like`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501).

```
select customerfield
from CustomerTable
where not regexp_like(CustomerField, '^N[0-9]{10}$')
```

This will show the customerfield's that don't follow the pattern specified.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to find the invalid characters in the string (and not to just simply find the strings that are invalid) perhaps this more complex query will help. You didn't state in what format you may need the output, so I made up my own. I also created several strings for testing (in particular, it is always important to check that the `NULL` input is treated correctly).

The column `len` shows the length of the input, if it's not 11. The length of the empty string (`null` in Oracle) is shown as 0. The `first-nondigit` columns refer to characters starting at the SECOND position in the string (ignoring the first character, for which the rules are different and which is checked for validity separately).

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (
       select 'N0123456789' from dual union all
       select ''            from dual union all
       select '02324434323' from dual union all
       select 'N02345678'   from dual union all
       select 'A2140480080' from dual union all
       select 'N93049c4995' from dual union all
       select 'N4448883333' from dual union all
       select 'PAR3993949Z' from dual union all
       select 'AN39E'       from dual
     )
-- end of test data; query begins below this line
select str,
       case when regexp_like(str, '^N\d{10}$') then 'valid'
            else 'invalid'                   end         as classif,
       case when length(str) != 11 then length(str)
            when str is null       then 0    end         as len,
       case when substr(str, 1, 1) != 'N' 
                      then substr(str, 1, 1) end         as first_char,
       regexp_substr(str, '[^0-9]', 2)                   as first_nondigit,
       nullif(regexp_instr( str, '[^0-9]', 2), 0)        as first_nondigit_pos
from   inputs
;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
STR          CLASSIF    LEN  FIRST_CHAR FIRST_NONDIG FIRST_NONDIGIT_POS
-----------  -------  -----  ---------- ------------ ------------------
N0123456789  valid
             invalid      0
02324434323  invalid         0
N02345678    invalid      9
A2140480080  invalid         A
N93049c4995  invalid                    c                             7
N4448883333  valid
PAR3993949Z  invalid         P          A                             2
AN39E        invalid      5  A          N                             2

9 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

\d stands for digit

[Perl-influenced Extensions in Oracle Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/ap_posix003.htm)

The rest if the regular expression elements can be found here

[Regular Expression Operator Multilingual Enhancements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/ap_posix002.htm)

```
select  *
from    CustomerTable
where   not regexp_like (CustomerField,'^N\d{10}$')
```

Comment: could you please explain your answer a little bit, and why you would choose to do it this way.  Thank you